# How to get enum content of another class in Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I want navigate to another view controller that have a picker view, but this is generic, the content pickview must be selected according a type parameter passed before navigate. This parameter is a variable named `tipo`

So in my MainViewController I have a func to navigate:

```
@objc func handlerSelectOpTipo(_ sender: UILabel) {
        let vcSelectTipo = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerSelect") as! ViewControllerSelect
       //  vcSelectTipo.tipo = .entrega // <- Example that I want.
        vcSelectTipo.tipo = 0 // <- ENUM TYPE HERE
        self.present(vcSelectTipo,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

Picker`s ViewController

```
class ViewControllerSelect : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btOk: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitulo: UILabel!
    var tipo : Int?
    var conteudo : [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        pickerView.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
        btOk.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlerBtOk), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func handlerBtOk() {

    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return conteudo.count
    }

    enum tipoConteudo: Int {
        case tipo
        case entrega
        case priceList
        case campanha
    }
}
```

I can't access enum values of MainViewController for set `var tipo : Int?`

I wants some like:

```
vcSelectTipo.tipo = .entrega
vcSelectTipo.tipo = .priceList
```

but the autocomplete not show `tipoConteudo` enum type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared the `tipo` variable as an `Int` instead of your enum type.

Change:

```
var tipo: Int?
```

to:

```
var tipo: TipoConteudo?
```

And type names should start with uppercase letters so `tipoConteudo` should be `TipoConteudo`.

Comment: this works, but why autocomplete (control+space) not works ?

Comment: Sometimes Xcode gets confused. Try restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change

```
var tipo: Int?
```

to

```
var tipo: tipoConteudo?
```

You just had the incorrect type for tipo.